# How to make certain parts of the textview to look bold?

Tags: android

I'm fetching the data from Contacts and displaying it in the textview. I want one part t be in Bold.How to do that. I tried doing this:
sb.append(Html.fromHtml("\n"+" **Contact Name:**" + name);
But it's not working..Can anyone please help me

Comment: use this `myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));` and here is the list of supported html tags http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Comment: Make sure you shave all its hair. P.S. please use Google to do some research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to format your string in html form during creation then apply formHtml method on whole string. Html.formHtml() method Returns displayable styled text(Spanned) from the provided HTML string. if you are applying this method on substring(with html tags) after that appending them to StringBuffer, sb.append(Html.fromHtml("\n"+" < b>Contact Name< /b>:" + name) actually calls Spanned.toString() method resulting in removal of html tags hence you are viewing plain text in text view.

try this way 
this will solve your problem

```
     StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
     sb.append("hello");
     sb.append("<b>How</b>");
     sb.append("are you");
     tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));
```

Comment: Thank you, now it worked..but problem is..its displaying in the same line,. I tried appending new line..but still its coming continuously..What might be the problem?

Comment: I tried this and it worked for me: StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(); s1="<b>\n Contact Name:</b>"; sb.append(s1+name+"\n"); s2="<b>\n Phone number:</b>"; sb.append( s2+phone+"\n"); s3="<b>\n Email:</b>"; sb.append(s3+emailContact); sb.append( "\n") txtv.setText(Html.fromHtml(sb.toString())); but problem is..its displaying in the same line,. I tried appending new line..but still its coming continuously..What might be the problem?

Comment: Hi thank you..It worked now..I used <br> instead of "\n" and now it working exactly how I expected

Comment: Hi I'm creating a simple student application form. I have given EditText for address as multiline. The problem I'm facing is that EditText gets overlapped with my button. Is there any way to automatically change the button position as i press enter in the Edit Text?

Answer (score 0):

in your strings file

```
<string name="your_text">
<![CDATA[
<p> <b>Title</b> </p>
<p><b><i>Step 1</i></b><p>step1 content content content  content content content</p></p>
<p><b><i>Step 2</i></b><p>step2 content  content content content  content content content</p></p>
]]>
</string>
```

Then in your activity

```
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.your_text)));
```

-----------------OR-----------------------

Just build your String in HTML and set it:

```
    String sourceString = "<b>" + id + "</b> " + name; 
    mytextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way-

```
sb.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" +" Contact Name:" + name + "</b>"));
```

Reply back if this doesn't resolve the issue.

**UPDATE:**

If you only want to append the specified text to the TextView's display buffer then still your code is incorrect may be a typo.

You used this-

```
sb.append(Html.fromHtml("\n"+" Contact Name:" + name);
```

Instead use this -

```
sb.append(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+" Contact Name:" + name + "</b>"));
```

Note the `<b> tag` start and `</b> tag` end.

Also note that you haven't closed your end bracket with `)`

**UPDATE:**

I guess that sb is your `StringBuffer` and not the `TextView`. So you have to set this on a `TextView` and **not** in a `StringBuffer`.

Let your TextView is,

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ur_text_view_id);
```

Then you simply do the following ---

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b> Contact Name:</b>" + name));
```

**UPDATE:**

Since you are using StringBuffer to store all the contact details so just use the following-

```
 //the below in a loop to add each name to string buffer
 for(<loop through name length>)
    sb.append("<br>" + "<b>Contact Name</b>:" + name);

 //finally use this outside loop to set text to the textview.
 tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));
```

**NOTE:** The last UPDATE is only useful if the first line is in a loop appending each name in a string buffer. Otherwise you can directly use the second last UPDATE of this answer.

Comment: I tried this technique..But it doesn't becomes bold..And i want only the left part to be bold.

Comment: @sangeetha - Ok check my updated answer. This will make the left part to be bold.

Comment: @sangeetha - there is no need to append details just for this purpose as you have one dynamic field `name`. You can directly set this with `tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b> Contact Name:</b>" + name));` while fetching data.

Answer (score 0):

try using spanable text

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String s1 = "Contact Name:" ;
    sb.append(s1);
    String nameString = " name"; 
    sb.append(nameString);
    String s2 = "\nEmail :";
    sb.append(s2);
    String emailString = " email";
    sb.append(emailString);
    String s3 = "\nPhoneNo :";
    sb.append(s3);
    String phNoString = " 121564";
    sb.append(phNoString);
    SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(sb);
    ss1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0,s1.length(), 0);
    ss1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), s1.length() + nameString.length(),s1.length() + nameString.length()+s2.length(), 0);
    ss1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),s1.length() + nameString.length()+s2.length()+emailString.length(), s1.length()+nameString.length()+s2.length()+emailString.length()+s3.length(), 0);

    TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    tv.setText(ss1);
```

Comment: In my code. I'm retrieving the contact details and appending it to the string builder. But I want only certain part to be bold. So if i use spannableString, the no need to use StringBuffer?

Comment: you can use `StringBuffer` with `SpannableString`. as you can see in `s2` String I am appending `s` and `name` so you can use ` StringBuffer` instead of `s2 String`.

Comment: According to what u have said, the code looks like this:               s1="\n Contact Name:";       sb.append( s1+ name);                                                  But i have 2 more details to append(phone no & email id). So Howw to to do that. I mean if i used this:                                   SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(s2);      -->at the end, it will make only Contact Name Bold. How to make Phone Number & Email also to look bold?

Comment: see in line `ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0,s1.length(), 0);` second parameter is starting index and next parameter is ending index of substring which you want to `bold`. you can use this line multiple times to achieve your desired string.

Comment: your welcome. accept this as ans if it works for you

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(sb);
ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0,s1.length(), 0); 
ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0,s2.length(), 0); 
ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0,s3.length(), 0); 
//Set the text to the text view
     txtv.setText(ss1.toString());
      
             }

Comment: I tried this inside onPreExecute since i used Async Task

Comment: And inside my method i wrote this:                                    s1="\n Contact Name:";  
sb.append(s1 + name);                                                  s2 for Phone number & s3 for email

Comment: I have updated my ans check it. it will give result as you wanted

Comment: check your textView Id. may be it is not matching to yours

Comment: I tried this and it worked for me:                                    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
s1="<b>\n Contact Name:</b>";
sb.append(s1+name+"\n");                                            s2="<b>\n Phone number:</b>";
sb.append( s2+phone+"\n");                                          s3="<b>\n Email:</b>";
sb.append(s3+emailContact);
sb.append( "\n")      
txtv.setText(Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));                but problem is..its displaying in the same line,. I tried appending new line..but still its coming continuously..What might be the problem?

Comment: you have not tried my code, I tried it and it before updating. Just try it.

Comment: I tried it...Even ur code works,..but it became bold in the 2nd part also(not all,few..). I think that is bcoz of the index which I gave. I'll try giving correct index and update you soon

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

```
        SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("HELLOO");
        final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD); // Span to make text bold
        sb.setSpan(bss, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); // make first 4 characters Bold 
        etx.setText(sb);
```

**2.**

```
        etx.setText(Html.fromHtml("HELLOO <b>ADVENTURE!</b>"));
```

try above code.

Comment: Since i used to Stringbuffer to append text.Now to use SpannableStringBuilder,i need to know the index. So how to know the index of the text dynamically. Because i have appended name,phone number and email id.